# Want to open SOLMAN_WORKCENTER Tcode in mobile device

Tags: sap-fiori

i want to open SOLMAN_WORKCENTER Tcode in mobile device.
what should i prefer web browser or FIORI client application?
Please suggest the prerequisite for this and possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The official [SAP docu](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_sm71_sp10/helpdata/en/40/8ac473d40943ddb23def12bdb33437/content.htm)  might be helpful:

Starting the Work Center
You can start all work centers for which you are authorized, as follows:

1) In the SAP GUI for Windows using transaction SOLMAN_WORKCENTER

2) In a Web browser using the Web Dynpro application AGS_WORKCENTER

Note 
By default, the URL for calling up the Web Dynpro application (in the SAP namespace) has the following syntax:

```
http://< host >:< port >/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/ags_workcenter?sap-language=< e.g.: EN>.
```

Do not use the Back button for navigating in your Web browser.

You can also start an individual work center directly using the corresponding Web Dynpro application. To call up the URL, for example, for Incident Management (in the SAP namespace), use the following syntax:

```
http://< host >:< port >/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/ags_work_incident_man?sap-language=< e.g.: EN>
```

3) In SAP NetWeaver Business Client (NWBC)

Here you have the same navigation options as in the Web browser but the system arranges the UI elements differently: In NWBC, the navigation bar is vertical and the navigation area is horizontal. For more information, see SAP Library for SAP NetWeaver Business Client on SAP Help Portal at   http://help.sap.com/netweaver ->  SAP NetWeaver Platform  ->  ->  Application Help ->   Function-Oriented View ->     UI Technologies in SAP NetWeaver  -> User Interface Clients .